# How to open a Directory with C++

Tags: c++, directory

I am very new to C++, and for my first assignment I am asked to open a directory ( and all its subdirectories) and store ONLY the .txt file paths in an array. This is what I've done so far, but I've gotten multiple errors. Could anyone help?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<string>
#include<dirent.h>

using namespace std;

void explore(char *dir_name){
    DIR *dir; // pointer to directory
    struct dirent *entry; // all stuff in the directory
    struct stat info; // info about each entry

    dir = opendir(dir_name);

    if (!dir)
    {
        cout << "Directory not found" << endl;
        return;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (entry->d_name[0] != '.')
        {
            string path = string(dir_name) + "/" + string(entry->d_name);
            cout << "Entry = " << path << endl;
            stat(path,&info) //
            if (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
            {
                explore(path);

            }

        }
    }
    closedir(dir);

}

int main{
    explore(".");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `boost::filesystem`

Comment: It should be `int main()`, not just `main`. You need to study more! By the way, boost is not necessary.

Comment: If you're just getting started learning, [you may as well learn up-to-date C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). Note: This may screw with your instructor's head. Odds are way too good they've never even heard of C++'s filesystem library.

Comment: Check if your compiler supports C++17 `#include <filesystem>`.

Comment: You can try writing *less code* before compiling so you know when you get a piece of syntax wrong and you only have one error to fix at a time.

Comment: Looking the code over, you're mostly missing grammar `int main`->`int main()` and `stat(path,&info)`->`stat(path,&info);`, and you need to get `char *`s from your `string`s with `c_str()`. Reccomend removing most of the `char*`, by the way., You can use `string` everywhere except `stat(path.c_str(),&info)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on Linux right? Why are you complicating things? There is something called "file tree walk" that will do exactly what you want with minimal effort. Here is a quick example. Do `man ftw` for more information on the input parameters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ftw.h>
#include <fnmatch.h>

static int explore( const char *fpath,
                    const struct stat *sb,
                    int typeflag )
{
    if (typeflag == FTW_F)  ///< it's a file
    {
        if (fnmatch("*.txt", fpath, FNM_CASEFOLD) == 0) ///< it's a .txt file
        {
            std::cout << "found txt file: " << fpath << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    ftw(".", explore, 8);
    return 0;
}
```